# Setting Spark driver memory in Zeppelin on Docker (local mode)

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I checked many resources such as:

- https://github.com/dylanmei/docker-zeppelin
- http://bigdatums.net/2017/02/26/running-apache-zeppelin-on-docker/

But non has a clear way to set the driver memory, I tried to set variables like:

- `-e SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--driver-memory 6G"` and
- `-e ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.driver.memory=6g"`

without any success.

Here is my full command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
-p 4040:4040 \
-v $PWD/logs:/logs \
-v $PWD/notebook:/notebook \
-v $PWD/jars:/jars \
-v $PWD/conf/interpreter.json:/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.js \
-v $PWD/data:/data \
-e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' \
-e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' \
-e SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--driver-memory 6G" \
apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some investigations I had to add `-e ZEPPELIN_INTP_MEM="-Xmx6g"` to the options.